# Frameset innerHTML changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to achieve something like, www.example.com/en/test/page.html will load the frameset of www.example.com/2.html.

Which I am able to do.

But now once `2.html` is loaded in frameset I want to replace `.html"` to `.html" target="_top"`.

So that all the links present in `2.html` would be opened in the parent window instead of frameset itself.

```
<!DOCTYPE html">
<html lang='en' xml:lang='en' xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8" />
                    <title>Test Page</title>
                            <script> 
                            (function divert()
                                    {
                                    var urlString = parent.document.URL;
                                    var a1 = new RegExp("/en/test/page");
                                    if(a1.test(urlString))    {document.write('<frameset cols="100%" rows="100%"><frame src="http://www.example.com/2.html"></frameset>');}
                                    else{document.write('<frameset cols="100%" rows="100%"><frame src="http://www.example.com/3.html"></frameset>');}

                                    var str = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML; 
                                    var res = str.replace('.html"', '.html" target="_top"');
                                    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;
                                    })();
                            </script>
    </head>
    <body onLoad="divert()"></body>
```

Comment: Why don’t you just write `target="_top"` on all those links in the HTML in the first place?

Comment: Because the frameset URL is not constant and we cannot modify the code for all the pages that will be used.

Answer (score 0):

Hi @Vinod you can use `target="_parent"`if you have only 2 level of frame-set or just want to open the link to the parent frame only..

Or to open the link to the current page you can use `target="_top"`

You can read more about it [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp)

**UPDATE:**

You can also use JavaScript to detect if page is loaded inside a frame and than add target to the links pragmatically..

You can use `window.location.origin` and `parent.window.location.origin` to detect if you are in the frame

And than you can use following code to add target using JavaScript

using jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#link_other a').attr('target', '_blank');
});
```

without using jquery

```
window.onload = function(){
  var anchors = document.getElementById('link_other').getElementsByTagName('a');
  for (var i=0; i<anchors.length; i++){
    anchors[i].setAttribute('target', '_blank');
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes i can use target="_parent" as well. But the main problem is adding this automatically/dynamically for the URL that is loaded in frameset. I am sure there has to be a way.

Comment: Hi Pratick, If i add the below code in console, it works 

`var links = document.getElementById("demo").contentDocument.documentElement.getElementsByTagName('a');

for(var i =0; i<links.length; i++){
links[i].target = '_parent';}`

But if i add it back to my html its not doing any thing. Can you please help. Thanks a lot for you help..

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html">
<html lang='en' xml:lang='en' xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8" />
                    <title>Test Page</title>
                            <script> 
                            (function divert()
                                    {
                                    var urlString = parent.document.URL;
                                    var a1 = new RegExp("/en/test/page");

                                function targetUrl(){
                                 var links = document.getElementById("demo").contentDocument.documentElement.getElementsByTagName('a');
                                 for(var i =0; i<links.length; i++){
                                 links[i].target = '_parent';}
                                }

                                    if(a1.test(urlString)){document.write('<frameset cols="100%" rows="100%"><frame id="demo" src="http://www.example.com/2.html"></frameset>');}
                                    else{document.write('<frameset cols="100%" rows="100%"><frame id="demo" src="http://www.example.com/3.html"></frameset>');}
                                    document.getElementById("demo").onload= targetUrl;
                                    })();
                            </script>
    </head>
    <body></body>
</html>
```